# How to store the contents of a file into an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsbundle

Well this is embarrassing and I saw a lot of questions answered, and I copied a lot of answers but no one works for me, I'm new in objective C and I know the rules here, I googled it, I saw a lot a pages of objective C, Xcode, Programming, C, Forums, blogs, and here, I'm getting Nuts. Here is my think

The code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSError *error = NULL;
        NSString* pathFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file"
                                                                  ofType:@"txt"];
        NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathFile
                                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                               error:&error];
        if (error)
            NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"%@", content);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Its very simple, in the original app it is complex but this is the part where Im getting troubles.

And heres the files in the buble...

[image]

Heres is the result:

```
2014-04-28 21:45:17.213 LeerFile[6930:303] Error reading file: The file name is invalid.
2014-04-28 21:45:17.214 LeerFile[6930:303] (null)
```

And finally here is the Build phases...

[image]

Guys, please, help me with this, I try it but I don't know what Im doing wrong or how to fix it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're copying the file into /usr/share/man/man1/, but you're looking for the file in your bundle's resources folder. You need to copy the file into the resources folder, or pass a different path to `[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:];`.

Also you've checked "Copy only when installing," meaning that it won't copy the files in your debug build.

Comment: Perfect. I write /usr/share/man/man1/file on the pathForResource and works fine, but how can i store it into the resources folder? I thought that was kept in the resource folder when dragged in my project.

Comment: You can change the Destination pop-up menu in the Copy Files phase from "Absolute Path" to "Resources".